# Install GNU Toolchain on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, gcc

I am following a tutorial which requires me to have the GNU toolchain installed - *(gcc, ld, gas, etc)*. I know I can get `gcc` in `build-essential`. However, how do I get the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs like `as` and `ld` are part of the GNU `binutils` package. The package management system will install this automatically as a dependency of the compiler: if you have installed `build-essential` there should be nothing extra you need to do.

*This assumes you are referring to the native GNU compiler toolchain: things may be different if you are referring to a toolchain for cross-compilation.*

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html). I guess I need the native GNU toolchain, right? :)